# Bootstrap datepicker default date

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm using Bootstrap datepicker and I'd like to make that when datepicker shows, default date would be set after 14 days from today. I've got this code but it doesn't work, default date is still set to today. Could anyone explain what am I missing? Thanks in advance.

JS:

```
  var plus14days = new Date();

  plus14days.setDate(plus14days.getDate() + 14 );
  $(".datepicker").datepicker("setValue", plus14days);
```

Comment: Are you calling it within `$(document).ready()`?

Answer (score 13):

The code you've used is right.

**The date will be displayed in `textbox`, but not in datepicker calendar** like this

[image]

To enable this feature you need to update it using the following code:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker('update');
```

Now it looks like

[image]

Check this in [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/BjtNY/381/)

Comment: This solution doesnt work for me anymore. Any ideas why?

Comment: @EntityBlack not sure.  the JSFiddle in my answer works fine.  I've checked their [update](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/methods.html#update) and they haven't changed any.  You must have other issues in your code.

Comment: I think I might isolate the issue. The problem is only if I dont modify the  date `.datepicker('update', new Date());`

Answer (score 4):

Just a consideration, 
api changed setValue to setDate (http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/methods.html#setdate)

Answer (score 0):

```
var plus14days = new Date();

plus14days.setDate(plus14days.getDate() + 14 );
$('.datepicker').data("date", plus14days);
$(".datepicker").datepicker();
```

You can try to set the default date in datepicker data and then initialize the datepicker. This worked for me.