# Date Picker always show from the year 0 when pop up

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

When load the page, I've set the date to datepicker.. But when it's pop up, it always show from january 0(year). why is like that.

I am using Bootstrap datepicker.

**In my text box the date is 28 nov 2013 . But this date is not highlighted in datepicker widget

**

**But on change works perfectly. I don't know why ?**

Comment: **In my text box the date is 28 nov 2013 . But this date is not highlighted in datepicker widget


**

**But on change works perfectly. I don't know why ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You have to [**update**](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/methods.html#update) the date in `bootstrap datepicker` widget in order to see it in the calender*, after setting the date.

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker('update');
```

Check this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18330989/1671639) for pictorials.

```
var plus14days = new Date();
plus14days.setDate(plus14days.getDate() + 14);
$("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", plus14days); //set 14 days prior
$("#datepicker").datepicker('update'); //once updated you can it in datepicker
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", new Date());

//Auto Closing     
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
        "setDate": new Date(),
        "autoclose": true
});
```

This will initialize  the date picker with the today's date that will avoid your problem

Hope this helps..